# Error occurs when a where clause is used with a table valued function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have the following table valued UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funParseRestParams](
    @Params NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delim VARCHAR(100))
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS

        RETURN (
            SELECT 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([Argument], 1, CHARINDEX('=', [Argument], 1) - 1))) Parameter,
                LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([Argument], CHARINDEX('=', [Argument], 1) + 1, LEN([Argument]) - CHARINDEX('=', [Argument], 1)))) Value
            FROM (          
                SELECT 
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Params, [Number], CHARINDEX(@Delim, @Params + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number]))) [Argument]
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) [Number]
                    FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
                WHERE Number <= LEN(@Params) AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @Params, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim) AS y);

GO
```

I'm running this in a cursor using the parameters string from `ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLogStorage`.  Parameters look something like this: "Some%20Param%20Name=Hello&Some%20Other%20Param=NoLuck"

When I run the function in a cursor like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Reports.dbo.funParseRestParams(@Param, '&')
```

Everything comes out fine, but when I add a where clause:

```
    SELECT * FROM Reports.dbo.funParseRestParams(@Param, '&') R 
    WHERE R.[Parameter] = 'AccessType'
```

I get the following error message every time:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 13
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

So why does my where clause kill the function?

EDIT:  Adding something extra.  You can paste the code below into SQL Server to replicate this error.  The error only occurs when using the "first" column, the Parameter column in the where clause.  Using the "second" Value column in the where clause does not cause the error.  You can remove commenting below to see this in action:

```
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Delim VARCHAR(1)

SET @Params = 'Greeting=Hello&Name=George&Dessert=Jello'
SET @Delim = '&'

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([Argument], 1, CHARINDEX('=', [Argument], 1) - 1))) Parameter,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([Argument], CHARINDEX('=', [Argument], 1) + 1, LEN([Argument]) - CHARINDEX('=', [Argument], 1)))) Value
    FROM (          
        SELECT 
            LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Params, [Number], CHARINDEX(@Delim, @Params + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number]))) [Argument]
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) [Number]
            FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
        WHERE [Number] <= LEN(@Params) AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @Params, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim) AS y
) R 
--WHERE R.Parameter = 'AccessType'
--WHERE R.Parameter = 'Greeting'
--WHERE R.Value = 'Bananas'
--WHERE R.Value = 'Jello'
```

Comment: Do you get the same behavior running outside a cursor?  Have you identified the input values on the iteration of the cursor with the failure? Do you get this error right away on the first iteration or do some values work?  Finally, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: The only other thing I'd add is make sure a cursor is really necessary.

Comment: I do get the same error without the cursor.  I've tracked it down to just the where clause.  Even more odd, it only occurs when filtering the Parameter column and not the Value column.

Comment: The next step is to isolate the EXACT column value(s) that trip the condition.  That is, you need to determine the precise values that raise this error.  I believe you will find that they raise this error even without the "select"... Invoking the substring expressions with a set for example will also I believe produce the error.  Pay particularly close attention to the substring in the where clause itself with these values.

Comment: @KenClement Sorry, I was sick and had a few things going on in the past couple of days.  I added new code above so you can see the error yourself.  The error occurs with any filtering of the R.Parameter column in the where clause.  Filtering using R.Value does not cause the error.

Comment: @KenClement I got an answer over at MSDN.  Check it out.  Still seems like really odd behavior to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped by the MSDN to search for an answer and I got one.  I'm still looking at the details, but for some reason the following works where the original did not.  The second line of the first subquery is altered:

```
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Delim VARCHAR(1)

SET @Params = 'Greeting=Hello&Name=George&Dessert=Jello'
SET @Delim = '&'

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([Argument], 0, CHARINDEX('=', [Argument], 1) ))) Parameter,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([Argument], CHARINDEX('=', [Argument], 1) + 1, LEN([Argument]) - CHARINDEX('=', [Argument], 1)))) Value
    FROM (          
        SELECT 
            LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Params, [Number], CHARINDEX(@Delim, @Params + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number]))) [Argument]
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) [Number]
            FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
        WHERE [Number] <= LEN(@Params) AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @Params, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim) AS y
) R 

--WHERE R.Parameter = 'AccessType'
WHERE R.Parameter = 'Greeting'
--WHERE R.Value = 'Bananas'
--WHERE R.Value = 'Jello'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider something like the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Moden
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;
```

This code is attributed to Jeff Moden [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).  This site also has other approaches.  It may be worth adopting a well-vetted solution (You must also vet it for yourself) rather than trying to reinvent the wheel and having to spend inordinate time debugging it as well.